# How can I divide spreadsheet rows by a time period?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a list of transactions in Google Sheets, and each row has a timestamp. It looks like this:

```
21 Feb 07:33 - Transaction A
21 Feb 10:03 - Transaction B
21 Feb 19:11 - Transaction C
22 Feb 02:01 - Transaction D
22 Feb 09:21 - Transaction E
22 Feb 09:45 - Transaction F
```

These transactions occur in a 24-hour period, but that period day starts at 8am and goes until 7:59am the next day. (Note that transactions can occur at any time, as you see in my example data.)

I want to **draw a dividing line in my sheet between each period.** So if you're looking at my example data above, I want a line **below Transaction A** (since that is the last transaction in that 24-hour period) and another **below Transaction D** (since again, that is the last transaction for that period).

Comment: Use conditional formatting by formula. Get date from current cell value, add 8 hours to it, and compare this datetime with current and RC[-1] cell value. If the datetime is below the value of current cell and above the value of RC[-1] cell, then draw upper border line.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly how I'd do this. Could you tell me what the formula would look like in the "Format cells if... custom formula is" box?

Comment: Also: I found this but it's really confusing and I can't get it to work on my sheet at all. https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8778036?hl=en

Comment: @Akina probably thought you meant Excel, since you tagged your question with Excel.